# Apply list-style-type only on the parent, not the children

Tags: html, css

I have an ordered list with a specific value for the `list-style-type` property and I want it to not affect its children.

Currently, the ordered list has another ordered list nested inside and it inherits the `list-style-type` value. How can I disable that?

```
 <ol class='custom-ol'>
  <li> cat1:
    <ol style="list-style-type:lower-alpha">
     <li>text 1</li>
     <li>text2</li>
     </ol>
  </li>
  <li>
    cat2:
     <ol style="list-style-type:lower-alpha">
     <li>text 3</li>
     <li>text 4</li>
     </ol>
  </li>
```

the css style

```
    <style>
   .custom-ol ol
    {
        counter-reset: custom-counter;
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    .custom-ol ol li 
    {
          counter-increment: custom-counter;
    }

    .custom-ol ol li:before 
    {
          content:"(" counter(custom-counter) ") ";
          font-weight:bold;
   }

</style>
```

I tried to fix to that way but it's not working at all (update version)

that's what i get

```
ol.custom-ol
{
    counter-reset: custom-counter;
    list-style-type: none;
}
ol.custom-ol li 
{
      counter-increment: custom-counter;
}

ol.custom-ol li:before 
{
      content:"(" counter(custom-counter) ") ";
      font-weight:bold;
}

ol ol {
    list-style-type: lower-alpha;
}
```

[image]

I want the parent (where is 1 now will be (1) with the **. custom-ol**  class
and his children be as they are a,b,c without the (1), (2)

Answer (score 0):

This is what your CSS should look like:

```
ol.custom-ol
{
    counter-reset: custom-counter;
    list-style-type: none;
}
ol.custom-ol li 
{
      counter-increment: custom-counter;
}

ol.custom-ol li:before 
{
      content:"(" counter(custom-counter) ") ";
      font-weight:bold;
}

ol ol {
    list-style-type: lower-alpha;
}

ol ol li:before {
    content: "";
}
```

Comment: the selector in css?

Comment: @AdirZoari Yes, that one

Comment: look on my edit in post. I tried to fix what you suggest it not working.

Comment: @AdirZoari I edited my answer, try that and let me know if it works, please

Comment: hey, this way make the same problem but something weird happen.. the parent is regular type list style like 1,2,3 and his parent is a b c and (1) (2) (3)

Comment: @AdirZoari Which of the two solutions I suggested are you trying?

Comment: yes. look on my edit post, I publish photo of what i got

Comment: @AdirZoari Okay, I changed my answer. Try it, please

Comment: look on my update post, I publish what I wrote and what i got. same issue.

Comment: @AdirZoari Okay I think I finally fixed it. Please try my new code (I edited my answer)

Comment: sorry, but no.. look on the post edit. I never think it complicate issue.

Comment: Let me see if I understand what you want: You want the outer ol to have a list-style-type of none and the inner ol to have list-style-type of lower-alpha?

Comment: the outer ol to have list style as in custom-ol class as (1) then another il to be (2) and the inner ol to be as it defined in list-style-tyle:lower-alpha. don't forget i have long code and i have also parent->child->child->child and it child also can be another list-style-type and i don't want it to be effect each other

Comment: @AdirZoari I edited my answer again try it now please

Comment: your answer is specific. i have more text with another list-style-type and it's not only lower-alpha it also lower-roman so i think your answer will not fit to me.

Comment: I'm quite sure the code I added will get rid of the (1) numeration in the inner `li`s. Is it doing that?

Comment: @Adir Okay then I don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

You're not targeting your parent `ol` at all and you're targeting the children `ol` elements twice. Once through inline styling:

`style="list-style-type:lower-alpha"`

and once through your CSS file:

```
.custom-ol ol
    {
        counter-reset: custom-counter;
        list-style-type: none;
    }
```

If you want to disable `list-style-type: none` on the children elements, then change `.custom-ol ol` to `.custom-ol`. This will target your parent `ol` only.

Alternatively, try adding `!important` to `style="list-style-type:lower-alpha"` like this:

`style="list-style-type: lower-alpha !important"`

This will override any other styles applied to the child `ol`.

Comment: I tried to make !important and this style same problem.

Comment: Can you be more specific as to the style you want to apply and to what element?